# How to store rules in database and access them in java files instead of using .drl files in Drools?

Tags: java, database, rules, drools

I am using Drools project and want to store rules in database as they will be configurable, even when application is running. I have searched on internet but didn't find any satisfactory result.

My requirement is:

"How to store rules in database and access them in java files instead of using .drl files?"

If you have any idea or sample example to demonstrate the same, please share.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Drools Guvnor uses JCR ( JackRabbit or ModeShape ) you can set them to save your rules into database. It also provides you tools for editing the rules and managing your knowledge packages. It is a bit more than your asking for, but might give you an idea on how to do the db storing.

Comment: So now we store rules using guvnor in database and access that database using another java application? @Toni